# Pre tag issue in php

Tags: php, opencart

Actually, I have added one `textarea` in my `opencart` admin panel I fetch the `textarea` value to front end but it is not coming properly it coming HTML format, I fixed HTML format also but Pre tag is not working, Lines & showing paragraph only please help me how to resolve this,

<kbd>admin product_form.tpl</kbd>

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-desc<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $entry_desc; ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea name="product_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][short_description]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_desc; ?>" id="input-short_description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" class="form-control summernote">
            <?php echo isset($product_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description[$language['language_id']]['short_description'] : ''; ?>
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>catelog product.tpl</kbd>

```
<div class="short_description form-group" itemprop="description">
    <h5 itemprop="name">Description:</h5>
    <?php 
    $short_descriptions = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($short_descriptions, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); 
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($short_descriptions);
    echo '</pre>';
    print_r($short_descriptions); 
</div>
```

Comment: What is the code for the textarea?

Comment: $short_descriptions = nl2br($short_descriptions)

Comment: $short_descriptions = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($short_descriptions, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                        $short_descriptions = nl2br($short_descriptions);
      echo $short_descriptions;

Comment: i tried but same only paragraph only coming not coming pre tag format.

Comment: Did you close the <?php tag properly with ?> ?

Comment: Please don't use `<kbd>` tag for formatting file names.